# why do SSRS reports run longer for a particular user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs

We have been receiving complaints from a particular SSRS user that her reports run slow.  I investigated in the `ExecutionLog` table in the `ReportServer` database and I observed something strange.

Fairly consistently, the `TimeDataRetrieval` is much longer than other users.  Both `TimeProcessing` and `TimeRendering` are near the averages of other users.

I am puzzled.  The reports all use the same shared data source that runs as a service account.  I would think if it was a crappy user computer issue, I would see differences in the rendering time.  Same if there was a network issue.

I don't know where else to look - any ideas?

Comment: Does the report accept any input parameters from the user?  If so, try two separate users supplying the exact same parameters.

Comment: No input parameters... good idea, though!

Comment: Check the SET settings for her session (sys.dm_exec_sessions). I wonder if she has different SET ARITHABORT or other settings compared to the other users, in which case she might be getting a different plan for the same underlying query.

Comment: Try logging in to her workstation under a different user - if it is still slow you know it has nothing to do with the user and is probably workstation/network specific.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - would the session be on the ReportServer or the source database?

Comment: Session is on the server, and it would be on the server where the underlying query is being run. `sys.dm_exec_sessions` is not database-specific.

Comment: Whoa, @AaronBertrand - you have opened my eyes to something that may also solve other issues we have... !  Commencing investigation...

Comment: Have you tried having the same user execute the report from a different machine using their same credentials?

Comment: @AaronBertrand If you'd like, move your comment about ARITHABORT into an answer and I'll accept!  This seems to have been the problem!

Comment: @JFHB - Don't jump to the conclusion that `ARITHABORT` is the actual problem. It just means that user will not have been sharing the same cached plans as others.

Comment: @MartinSmith -'ARITHABORT' explained my question, though... am I missing something?

Comment: @JHFB - If you came to the conclusion that `ARITHABORT` itself was to blame then yes. The issue was likely parameter sniffing. The reason why `ARITHABORT` appeared to fix it was because changing the value of that means you get a different cached plan that was compiled with different parameter values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converted to answer, per OP.

Check the SET settings for her session (sys.dm_exec_sessions). I wonder if she has different SET ARITHABORT or other settings compared to the other users, in which case she might be getting a different plan for the same underlying query.